# How to count record month group with unix timestamp in php & mysql.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Example my_table

```
ID | Name | Date
--------------------------
12 | John | 123456789
13 | Mike | 987654321
...
29 | Rick | 123498765
30 | Adam | 987651234
```

show output result like this

```
Month | Count
--------------------------
3 | 5 | 
6 | 8 |
```

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: You need to calculate the start and end of the month in epoch time, then use a BETWEEN type MySQL query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using MySQL Query as below.

```
SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`)) `Month`
    ,COUNT(ID)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY `Month`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since post tagged [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter)

This is codeigniter way:

```
$query = $this->db->select("month(from_unixtime(`Date`)) as `month`, count(1) as `count`",FALSE)
                  ->group_by("month");
                  ->get("your_table");
```

Comment: In this answer can we add 1 column called "names" with adding comma separate names, 
for example, month value is 3 then cell show 3 names in comma separares. Can you able to share the lines of code ? so its help to getting name list in single sql query. Thanks.